# Condition not working in PrimeNG table row

Tags: angular6, primeng

I am using **PrimeNG control** for developing a system. In one of my page, a Grid is populated using PrimeNG Table. Now I would like to change the background color of some rows where Current Date is greater than of a particular date value. to do this I have written the below code.

In my angular .ts file, I declared date field

```
this.currentDate = new Date();
```

In the HTML file, the condition is used below:

```
<tr [ngClass]="(currentDate | date) > (rowData.ValidTill | date) ? 'inactive-package' : 'null'">
```

Now the problem is, this condition returns true all the time and makes all of my grid rows colored. Can anyone describe why the condition returns true always? And give me suggestions to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the reason and got the solution. The condition was not working because of **currentDate** value and **rowData.ValidTill** value format was not the same. So in the controller file, I had to format the **rowData.ValidTill** in the same format like **currentDate** and now it's working fine.